# ASP.NET MVC: Remove unused/not supported query string values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string

How do I clear/remove query string parameters, which my MVC action, doesn't require/support?

For instance, my action requires, say an id and a bool flag, so the url would be something like: `http://localhost:someport/controller/action/?id=1&remove=true`

But, if a user types in something like, `http://localhost:someport/controller/action/?id=1&remove=true&some-junk-param=0`

Then, I want the `some-junk-param` to be removed and not shown in the address bar, when the request is processed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Only by checking the query string values in the method, and then redirecting back again to the method with out the 'invalid' values (you cannot control what the user types in the address bar).

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Or may be it is better to get rid of the query string completely, once the request is processed! I have noticed, some applications do that, at least, non ASP.NET ones!

Comment: That would not work too well if the user uses the 'Back' button in their browser

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get rid of unwanted query string parameters, you have two general options:

1. **Do it on server-side.** You can achive this only with redirection, that means when browser asks URL with bad query string, server redirects browser to URL with good query string.

Caveats:

- *In this case we have redundant query just for cleaning query string.*
- *User will have trash in browser history.*

---

2. **Do it on client-side.** ASP.NET MVC Model binder will get only expected parameters from query string, so it's nothing bad with having other values in query string. You can check your URL on client-side with javascript and rewrite it with or without changing history using [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) (IE10+).

Caveats:

- *In this case you will have to support consistency about allowed parameters between JS and C# code*

---

Of course every way is suitable for it's own cases, but looking at caveats the second way is better, because it affects developer expirience whereas first way affects user expirience.